# How to access apache solr server installed at google colab online?

Tags: python, information-retrieval, information-schema, cbir, content-based-retrieval

I am using Google Colab for apache solr 8.5.0 server implementation of Content Based Image Retrieval (CBIR) system, The solr is showing its port (8983), along with this, i have tried couple of IP addresses to access the solr server but failed.
Kindly help me that how i can access the apache solr server? which is installed on Google Colab platform.

`! /content/drive/MyDrive/solr-8.5.0/bin/solr start -c -force` 
output: Port 8983 is already being used by another process (pid: 6432)
Please choose a different port using the -p option.

```
! git clone https://github.com/dermotte/liresolr
% cd /content/drive/MyDrive/liresolr
! ./gradlew distForSolr
! mkdir -p /content/drive/MyDrive/data/mscoco/val2014
% cd /content/drive/MyDrive/data/mscoco/val2014
! wget http://images.cocodataset.org/zips/val2014.zip
! unzip val2014.zip
! find /content/drive/MyDrive/data/mscoco/val2014/val2014 -name "*.jpg" > val2014.txt

!  /content/drive/MyDrive/solr-8.5.0/bin/solr create -force -c lire_mscoco_val2014 -d /content/drive/MyDrive/solr-8.5.0/server/solr/configsets/lire-config/_default/
```

Output: Created collection 'lire_mscoco_val2014' with 1 shard(s), 1 replica(s) with config-set 'lire_mscoco_val2014'

```
! split -d -l 11000 /content/drive/MyDrive/data/mscoco/val2014/val2014_all_plus_ms.xml val2014_all_plus_ms_
! echo "</add>" >> val2014_all_plus_ms_00
! echo "</add>" >> val2014_all_plus_ms_01
! echo "</add>" >> val2014_all_plus_ms_02
! sed -i '1s/^/<add>/' val2014_all_plus_ms_01
! sed -i '1s/^/<add>/' val2014_all_plus_ms_02
! sed -i '1s/^/<add>/' val2014_all_plus_ms_03

! curl https://colab.research.google.com:8983/solr/lire_mscoco_val2014_shard1_replica_n1/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @/content/drive/MyDrive/data/mscoco/val2014/val2014_all_plus_ms_00
```

Output: When we used the localhost ip, the following response,  second time we add google colab url, then give connection timeout error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">25251</int>
</lst>
</response>
```